# How to get All options of a 'select' field?

Tags: 7

How can I get all options for a cck field?

For example, There is a field with 3 options in allowed values, like option1, option2, option3.Is there any function which receive the field name and returns option1 to option3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you can use [field_info_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7), while in Drupal 6 you can use [content_field_instance_read()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--cck--content_crud.inc/function/content_field_instance_read/5), which is defined in the CCK module.

As @Lauri said:

You can also use [list_allowed_values()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_allowed_values/7).

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name');
$allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field);
```

Answer (score 41):

You can also use [list_allowed_values()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_allowed_values/7).

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name');
$allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field);
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer.